# Big Theta Proof

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o, analysis

I got a practice exam question here asking if the following is true/false.

Let f , g, and h be functions from the natural numbers to the positive
real numbers. Then if g is an element of  Big Omega( f ) and g is an element of O(h), and f is an element of O(h) then g is an element of big Theta (h)

I got false for this but it is kind of confusing me now because I don't exactly know what Big omega(f) is.

Can someone clarify if my answer to this question is correct / if not, where I went wrong (and explain if possible please).

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation : see "The Knuth definition"

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Check the link I mentioned in the comment. g is an element of big Theta (h) <=> g is bounded both above and below by h, which is not the case. From your post it's only can be deduced that g is bounded above by h. So "false" is correct answer.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was thinking. Thank you so much for your quick response !